# Is there a graphical browser available for Ubuntu Core?

Tags: firefox, browser, snap, ubuntu-core, raspberrypi

I can't find a browser snap for Ubuntu Core. I'm doing `snap find firefox` or chromium or opera and nothing is returning a match.
Am I missing something here? I was wondering if it's because Ubuntu Core is supposed to be headless. I'm running it in a raspberry pi so I'm not even sure how a snap for a browser would have a UI when the raspberry pi gadget snap doesn't have an X Server. 
Surely something as basic as a browser would be available, no?

On top of it, google returns [this post](https://blog.mozilla.org/futurereleases/2016/04/21/firefox-default-browser-for-linux-users-ubuntu-new-snap-format-coming-soon/) from 2016 advertising a firefox snap but I can't find it

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind using a text based web browser, you could try [icey-lynx](https://uappexplorer.com/app/icey-lynx.icey) or [links](https://uappexplorer.com/app/links.zygoon).

Comment: text browsers are not an option. thank you